# How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, http, http-post, file-get-contents

I'm using PHP's function `file_get_contents()` to fetch contents of a URL and then I process headers through the variable `$http_response_header`.

Now the problem is that some of the URLs need some data to be posted to the URL (for example, login pages).

How do I do that?

I realize using stream_context I may be able to do that but I am not entirely clear.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#89080

Answer (score 662, accepted):

Sending an HTTP POST request using [`file_get_contents`](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents) is not that hard, actually : as you guessed, you have to use the `$context` parameter.

There's an example given in the PHP manual, at this page : [HTTP context options][2] *(quoting)* :

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Basically, you have to create a stream, with the right options *(there is a full list on that page)*, and use it as the third parameter to `file_get_contents` -- nothing more ;-)

As a sidenote : generally speaking, to send HTTP POST requests, we tend to use curl, which provides a lot of options an all -- but streams are one of the nice things of PHP that nobody knows about... too bad...

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing I can insert the contents from $_POST into $postdata if I need to pass same POST params to the requested page?

Comment: I suppose you can do something like that ; but `content` must not be a PHP array : it has to be a querystring *(i.e. it must has this format : `param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` )* ;; which means you'll probably have to use `http_build_query($_POST)`

Comment: Wonderful! I was looking for a way to pass POST data to another page which is achievable by doing `$postdata = http_build_query($_POST)`.

Comment: intresting enough this does not work for me at all i been tryiung it for a few hours and all my requets get turned into get querys

Comment: What if the parameters value are not strings but arrays or hashes etc ?

Comment: To send multiple header values, throw them all into one string with `\r\n` line breaks - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2107792/404960

Comment: Always add the option [ignore_errors => true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6041020/1119695) to get a more cURL like result. Otherwise `file_get_contents` will **only** return `false`, if there is an HTTP error status code delivered by the server. Just in case if you are working with some kind of API, which sets HTTP error status codes and you want to analyse the received message or error details.

Comment: To send raw XML post, change `header` to `Content-Type: text/plain` or `Content-Type: text/xml` and then set `content` to the XML. In my case, I usually don't send raw, unencrypted XML. I usually use `openssl_encrypt` with `aes-256-cbc` and a long password. But your needs may vary.

Comment: As of 2017: No matter all comments... This original answer is working SUPER GREAT. My only issue was NOT TO USE relative path to the target file to open, but the full URL. +1 (I'm using this to get email templates in different langages) ;)

Comment: Superb - I've never seen this technique before - I used it to POST JSON to a REST API and retrieve a JSON response.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using curl?

Comment: Passing an array payload converts the content-type header to `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 24):

An alternative, you can also use **fopen**

```
$params = array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => 'toto=1&tata=2'
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen($sUrl, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
{
    throw new Exception("Problem with $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}

$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) 
{
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this worked for me, but the PHP official example did not. +1 for the `toto=1&tata=2` as well. I didn't use the `fopen`, however.

Comment: @Ġiĺàɗ We don't call people 'noob' here.  This is a friendly warning against such.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sUrl = 'http://www.linktopage.com/login/';
$params = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => 'username=admin195&password=d123456789'
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen($sUrl, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if(!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}

$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $sUrl, $php_errormsg");
}
```

Comment: Please, try to provide an elaborated answer instead of simply copying/pasting code.

Comment: Also this is unnecessarily complicated. You can use `file_get_contents` instead of `fopen` + `stream_get_contents`. And you are not even closing the "file". See the accepted answer by @PascalMARTIN.