# No response with Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to pass my userid and password to the site www.licindia.in using curl, but I am getting trouble with cookies perhaps, I am unable to continue my session and the site response 302 error, the document has been moved temporarily, now I am getting no response with this code :-

```
<?php
    $username="myusername";
    $password="password";
    $url="http://onlinelic.in/LICEPS/Login/webLogin.do";
    //echo "praveenpuglai";
    $postdata = "portlet_5_6{actionForm.userName}=".$username."&portlet_5_6{actionForm.password}=".$password;
    $cookie = "JSESSIONID";
    ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    //var_dump($ch);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  //  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    //echo $result;
    /*if($result != null)
    {
    header('Location: http://onlinelic.in/LICEPS/appmanager/Customer/CustomerHome');
    } */
//    curl_close($ch);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($info['http_code'] == 301 || $info['http_code'] == 302) {
        preg_match_all('|Location: (.*)\n|U', $response, $results);
        $location = implode(';', $results[1]);
        header("Location: $location");
        exit;
    } else {
        $response = substr_replace($response, '', 0, strpos($response, '<', 0));
        echo $response;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that you're not willing to follow any redirects with this statement:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

Setting the value higher or not specifying it will make cURL follow redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I am able to login but stil not able to use the account resulting Unauthorized access, I feel still cookies are not stored, I have used CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to store cookies generated by curl in the cookie.txt but I dont know why its not working.

Comment: Within the same cURL session cookies are already kept automatically; you only need a cookie jar file when you create a new instance using `curl_init()`

Comment: Hmmm...I am using cookie jar file called cookie.txt for storing cookie information and also using COOKIEFILE for sending back that information to the sever but that's not working..
`   $cookie = "cookie.txt"
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    `

Comment: Why do you have `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`? That would disallow session cookies, which is probably what you need.

Comment: You may be collecting the cookies in cURL, but when you receive a 301/302 you redirect the browser to that location ... but of course, that browser won't have the cookies that you gathered in cURL ... so this will NEVER work.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,that is the problem. I am using CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE for sending back the stored information to the server,but it doesnt seems to work. Is this the right method, if not then how can I correct this thing..?

Comment: cookies are stored in the apache server folder now I ve to send back this file to the server.how to send this information and continue my session in that server..?

Comment: @avinashse well, have you considered using an absolute path to the cookie file instead of just `JSESSIONID`? I'm assuming all scripts run on the same server btw.

Comment: No, I have used `JSESSIONID` only as my path which I have posted in my code.
the site which i am trying to access with my userid and password and my script both are on different servers.

Comment: @avinashse then you need to find a way to transport those cookies from one server to the other.

Comment: Can You tell me how can I check the session of a website on different server ?

Comment: @avinashse I don't think this is possible with cURL at all.

Comment: Thanks for answering me,can yo tell me how can we do this, which language to be use.

Comment: It's just not possible. Period. You could set third party cookies maybe but I think you're just trying to solve the wrong problem altogether.

Comment: How can I set a third party cookies.. ??

Comment: Actually I have to store all details of lic agents in India. Link is www.licindia.in India, I have my user id and password, but there are numbers of agents and its not possible to do it manually,I think that site don't have an api so I dont know how to do that. I am having basic idea of php,javascript and curl, now can u please guide me in this direction ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $username="XXXXXX";
    $password="YYYYYY";
    $url="url"; 
    $capt="ZZZZZ"; 




    $postdata = "?{actionForm_userName}=".$username."&{actionForm_password}=".$password."&{actionForm_qreply}=".$capt;
    $cookie = "JSESSIONID";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

      //echo $cookie;
      //echo $postdata;
echo curl_error($ch);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    print($result);


curl_close($ch);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($info['http_code'] == 301 || $info['http_code'] == 302) {
        preg_match_all('|Location: (.*)\n|U', $response, $results);
        $location = implode(';', $results[1]);
        header("Location: $location");
        exit;
    } else {
        $response = substr_replace($response, '', 0, strpos($response, '<', 0));
        echo $response;
    }  

?>
```