# using file get contents on a url that requires post data

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

i need to do a "file_get_contents" on a URL and there has to be data posted to the url before the contents are retrieved. is this possible? maybe something like

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_POST"http://www.example.com/");
```

so that i can then work with the $contents variable?

Comment: Try [this link: How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents) and see if you can find something usable.

Comment: yes thank you, of course i found this link immediately after i asked my question XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot**** POST data using `file_get_contents`, you must use something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

*** I mark this because it is actually possible taking advantage of the third parameter which uses [http context(see example one).](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) However it really isn't worth your trouble if you have something like cURL.

Comment: I agree. Additionally, you shouldn't rely on `file_get_contents` to get URL data either.

Comment: the http context method seems to have done the trick, i realise i should be using cURL, i know its much stronger, but alas, im just looking for a quick fix and it seems the context trick has done the job. same with file_get_contents, i simply need it to extract 1 link, so it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have tried to do this. Simply put you can't unless you install new extra software on your sever and go through A LOT of hassel and server load.

Best bet is to use GET if at all possible!

:)