# 500 internal server error file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

If I try and read a sites' source I sometimes get the following (example URL shown):

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/gift-novelty/golf-ball-finding-glasses/10602617.html)
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /home/public_html/pages/scrape.html on line 165
```

Yet the URL on its own is fine.. why would this happen?

I tried the following workaround suggestion but same result:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$header = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com',false,$context);
```

This is baffling me now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need response body of HTTP 500 with file\_get\_contents (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040978/need-response-body-of-http-500-with-file-get-contents-php)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your User-Agent header. This worked for me:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$header = file_get_contents('http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/gift-novelty/golf-ball-finding-glasses/10602617.html',false,$context);
```

Comment: Even though this works this is not supposed how to use a User-Agent of course. How legal is this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact reason but while working with some servers, `file_get_contents` fails. But you have an alternative;

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.iwantoneofthose.com", 80, $errn, $errs);
$out  = "GET /gift-novelty/golf-ball-finding-glasses/10602617.html HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: www.iwantoneofthose.com\r\n";
$out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0\r\n";
$out .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$out .= "\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);

$response = "";
while ($line = fread($fp, 4096)) {
    $response .= $line;
} 
fclose($fp);


$response_body = substr($response, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n") + 4);
// or
list($response_headers, $response_body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

print $response_body;
```

Comment: What does the line before the `print` do? (`substr($resp...`)

Answer (score -3):

A "500 Internal Server Error" typically indicates that there's an issue on the server side when trying to fulfill a request. If you are encountering this error specifically with the file_get_contents function, it usually means that the server is unable to retrieve the specified resource.

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot this issue:

Check the URL: Ensure that the URL you're trying to fetch with file_get_contents is correct and accessible. Make sure there are no typos, and the resource you're trying to access is available.

Comment: Responses like this does not come close to helping user solving their issue. Also to be a response, it should suggest how to solve the issue.

Using ChatGPT and similar is not a good use for a forum like stackoverflow.