# Recaptcha V2 return false PHP

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, verification

I'm trying to implement Google ReCaptcha V2 in a PHP form.

**Here is my code :**

```
    $arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
    {
        //form submitted

        //check if other form details are correct

        //verify captcha
        $recaptcha_secret = "";
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if($response["success"] === true)
        {
            echo "Logged In Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "You are a robot";
        }
    }

?>
```

When i submit my form, it always return

> You are a robot

.

My public key is correct, and my private key too.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong ?

I'm working as localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when you do a `var_dump($response["success"]);`

Comment: It says "bool(false)"

Comment: are you passing `$secret` in url properly ?

Comment: Do `var_dump` on `$response`, it has error info there.

Comment: @KarloKokkak only if file_get_contents gets instructed via the stream context to return the response body even when the status code indicated an error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041020/1427878

Comment: @CBroe It still has error info coming from google.

Comment: @KarloKokkak not if the HTTP status code of the response indicated an error - file_get_contents discards the request body completely in such a case, unless you tell it otherwise beforehand.

Comment: By the error you're getting, make sure you have recaptcha properly setup client side.

Comment: You can use Web developer tool to debug that.

Comment: var_dump($responses) displays : "string(75) "{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }" You are a robot "

Answer (score 1):

Just integrated 2 days ago the V2 recaptcha from Google

Try my code below, explicitly to see if is solving your problem:

I can see u do file_get_contents, and i think here is your issues, u have to make  POST, please use my code below

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    // prepare post variables
    $post = [
        'secret' => $secret,
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        'remoteip'   => 'is optional, but i pass it',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($response);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    // check result
    if(isset($response['success']) && $response['success'] == true){
        echo "Logged In Successfully";
    }else{
        echo "You are a robot";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When i'm trying with your code, it says "string(75) "{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }" You are a robot "

Comment: make var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); what u get? do u use ajax for your form? seems $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] is not returning the key

Comment: @Tweakdev be sure that $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] hold the capcta response, i guess is returning empty string now from your form

Comment: var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); displays "NULL"

Comment: @Tweakdev because of this u have issue, the response is not in the formdata, your form is simple php form with refresh or u use ajax?

Comment: my form is in HTML with <form action="" method ="POST"> , maybe i have to do a PHP Form ?

Comment: @Tweakdev can u put all the code with the form and all php, to test it?

Comment: i put my HTML form as an answer, the PHP is as top of the page.

Comment: I found the solution @ionluchian , it was a problem of <div>. 
I had <div> and <form> after, but i have to put the <div> in the <form> , thanks for your time, you are a good guy