# Write message with bot after occured webhook event on STRIPE

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks, telegram-bot, endpoint

I'm setting my `webhook` **STRIPE** and i want to send message on `Telegram` when happen event in STRIPE (`checkout.session.completed` so after payment).

To set webhook is very easy so i'm sure the problem is really easy (just not for me).

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxx');

// You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_...';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
}

// Handle the checkout.session.completed event
if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
  $session = $event->data->object;

  // Fulfill the purchase...
  handle_checkout_session($session);
}

http_response_code(200);
```

If payment is successfull (so if `$event->type == 'checkout.session.completed'`) i want to write a message on telegram.
To write message is very easy:

```
    $url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=xxx&parse_mode=HTML&text=ok-webhook';    
    file_get_contents($url);
```

Why doesn't work ?
I tried to put it (code to write message) inside last `if` but nothing.
I know payment works because i can read the request to my endpoint and status code 200 (OK).

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Well the most simple step to start "debugging" would be to check what that telegram API URL you got there returns when you call it directly in a private browser window or tab ... I guess that will probably just be an error of some sorts, because I highly doubt telegram would let you send messages by just providing a chat ID, and no additional form of authentication beyond that whatsoever.

Comment: @04FS the strange thing is that telegram API URL is correct...if i paste that $url in browser (obviously inserting the real data of the bot and the chat_id) it writes message on my telegram group. So the problem is not about telegram method

Comment: @04FS no it is really so: D if you have a bot and you know the id of a chat (where the bot is admin) you can write the message without further authentication. I have a lot of bots and I know it's true. The problem in the case of this question is not about "how to write the message"

Comment: Well then you need to check what response you actually get when you make that API call from within your webhook setting - start by logging the return value of file_get_contents somewhere you can check it. (That might be just false - in that case, go read up on how to make the function return the actual response body in case of an error, it will not do that by default.)

Comment: @04FS can you help me ? how can i save the response ? (i'm not really god programmer with php).

Comment: No. My "go read up on" was deliberately phrased this way.

Comment: @04FS can you suggest me some question about my similiar problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040978/need-response-body-of-http-500-with-file-get-contents-php