# Tag friends in a Photo

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This is my code. It does not show any errors but only the first 2 friends are tagged!

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($friendsID);$i++)
{
 $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$upload_photo['id']."/tags/".$friendsID[$i]."?access_token=".$token."&x=80&y=".$y."&method=POST";
 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
 $post_url = urlencode($post_url);
 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
 $y = $y + 53;
}
```

I'm not receiving any error, but the code just does not tag all the people supposed to be tagged !

Answer (score 2):

According to the "Publishing" section in the [Facebook Developer API docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents), writes to the graph must be POST'ed.  Your request as written uses GET.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents) for how to convert your request to a POST.

As an aside, note that urlencode should only be applied to the parameters of a URL, not the entire URL.  Otherwise the colons & slashes in the base part of your URL will get encoded as well.