# file_get_contents and variables

Tags: php, http, post, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I have a text file filled with a list of IDs.
Using PHP, I am trying to load a url for each of the IDs and pull something from that page (another id)

For example, if I have the IDs 555, 888, 222
I want to load the URLs

http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=555

http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=888

http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=222

I tried to get the content via
`file_get_contents("http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=$lines[0]");`

where $lines is an array of the IDs.
This returns the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=222)    [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404
```

That url is an example, but the url in the error does work when I visit it manually. And if I replace the file_get_contents variable with an actual ID, like `?facultyID=222`, it works perfectly.

I visited this question's answer [How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents/2445332#2445332) and tried assigning  a variable in the $postdata array to a variable, and I get the same exact error only with `?facultyID=XXX` removed from the error message's url.

My implementation of the latter is [here](http://pastebin.com/yykLAePs).

Comment: What does print_r($lines) show?

Comment: Just tried it. The same error message appears with the id appended on the error message's URL

Comment: Do you hav `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini?

Comment: `print_r($lines)` shows `Array ( [0] => 813667 [1] => 1124279 [2] => 760643 [3] => 668461 [4] => 2868 [5] => 33613 )`                    Which are the correct IDs

Comment: On the off chance that there's something extra on those values, can you `urlencode` the IDs and try again?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen = On` is on my php.ini, yes. I am not familiar with `urlencode`, but I will look into it now

Comment: When using urlencode, it turns the error message url from              `?facultyID=813667` to `?facultyID=813667%0D%0A`. Not sure what to make out of this, does this mean that there are extra values being appended to the id?

Comment: Are the pages you are retrieving behind a log in page? In your browser a valid session would allow you to access the page, but the PHP script won't have the session open so might hit a 404?

Comment: There is a loginpage, but I found that when I clear my cookies and visit the links with the ID variables appended, no login is required. If PHP visits the link when I replace the variable `$lines[0]` with actual IDs,  it works fine. The problem is I need to use variables because I need to visit a ton of ids

Comment: Ok, hope you can figure this out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those encoded characters when you use the urlencode function (%0D%0A) are a new line, so maybe you array of id's have them in each element. Try this:

```
// your code to generate the lines array
file_get_contents("http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=" . trim($lines[0]));
```

Comment: I was just working on using str_replace to do that and those newline things were still appearing. Thanks, I love stackoverflow, haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = array(813667,1124279,760643,668461,2868,33613);
print_r($lines);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 813667 [1] => 1124279 [2] => 760643 [3] => 668461 [4] => 2868 [5] => 33613 )
```

this:

```
foreach($lines as $key => $value):
echo '<pre>';
print_r($lines[$key]);
endforeach;
```

output:

```
    813667
1124279
760643
668461
2868
33613
```

and this:
    $get = file_get_contents("http://example.edu/bvl.P_Sel?facultyID=$lines[0]");
    print_r($get);

output:

```
  Example Domains
  As described in RFC 2606,
    we maintain a number of domains such as EXAMPLE.COM and EXAMPLE.ORG
    for documentation purposes. These domains may be used as illustrative
    examples in documents without prior coordination with us. They are 
    not available for registration.
```

What is wrong? :) it's what you need?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I should have just gave the direct link i was using. it seems that it works for example.com but not for the actual domain i was visiting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CURL for scraping and also post data as it is more powerful and more advanced.