# Using proxy with file_get_contents

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

I am getting data for my application from a website, say x.com.
I use the php function  file_get_contents() to fetch the data.
It is sure that , my server's ip address will be shown in x.com 's logs.
Is there any way to hide my server's ip without using proxy?

**If I have a proxy ,how to use it with file_get_contents()** ?

I need to send the request in both HTTP POST and HTTP GET methods

Comment: file_get_contents take a param stream_or_context with it you can put your proxy into it see this  http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: i tried that ,but i got the following error that the content length is not specified .So I gave the arguments content length and offset .But  still it is not working .

Comment: the server side always know your ip or it cant exchange data with you (i mean http). in some case you can put a header like X-Forward-For: `fakeip` to tell server your fakeip, however the server side would determine which ip to use

Comment: @J what kind of proxy do you use

Comment: anonymous proxy - 221.176.14.72:80

Comment: is there an api,so that I just need to request to that URL

Comment: @J trying to make one for ya

Answer (score 25, accepted):

test.php using http://ifconfig.me/ip

code modified from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
<?php

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n",
            'proxy' => 'tcp://221.176.14.72:80',
            )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://ifconfig.me/ip', false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It is working..For post request I have to provide content type and length, right?

Comment: using post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents

Comment: I tested it on my server..and requested for a file on the same server and checked the logs..In the logs my server's ip is visible :(

Comment: it seems that proxy server added your ip to X-Forward-For and your server used it

Comment: any way to override?..:) is there an alternate way? :(

Comment: hiding based on how your server side read your ip. you can make a customized way if you know it

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree with farmer1992.

For anyone having issues with `file_get_contents` over SSL + proxy, there is a known bug with PHP's stream_context_create:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63519

Fortunately, the workaround is simple.  Basically, the context creator gets confused when parsing an "https" target URL to both the proxy and SSL configs.  You just have to set the **SNI_server_name** in the SSL config:

```
$targetUrl = "https://something.com";
$sniServer = parse_url($targetUrl, PHP_URL_HOST);
$params = array('your'=>'post','params'=>'here');
$ctxConfig = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."\r\n",
        'content' => http_build_query($params),
        'proxy' => 'tcp://12.34.56.78:3128',
        'request_fulluri' => true
    ),
    'ssl' => array( 
        'SNI_enabled' => true,
        'SNI_server_name' => $sniServer
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($ctxConfig);
file_get_contents($targetUrl,false,$context)
```

Hopefully that saves someone some time!

Comment: Thanks.  $params is just the POST params you intend to send to the server. I added a clarifying declaration above.

Comment: undefined variable $domain

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected this above.  What was `$domain` is now `$sniServer`.