# Sending post data along with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, html

I read this question from stackoverflow:
[How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents) 
which covers pretty much everything in order to explain as to how to use `file_get_contents()` function in php

To practice, I created these two php files :

**1.php**

```
<?php

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'name' => 'example',
        'roll' => '123321'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'post',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/2.php', false, $context);
echo $result;

?>
```

And this is my code for
**2.php**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$roll = $_POST['roll'];

echo $name . "<br>" . $roll;

?>
```

The expected output is that **1.php** should send "name" and "roll" to **2.php** using `method="post"` and get the contents of that file and print them like this :

**Expected Output :**

> Example
>   123321

**And this is the output that i am getting now (as if no POST data is sent)**

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\2.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: roll in C:\xampp\htdocs\2.php on line 4

Comment: ...aaaand instead it does what?

Comment: Why don't you use curl? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Comment: What does `var_dump($context)` give you?

Comment: @CBroe its giving me this output : "resource(2) of type (stream-context)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/de/context.http.php#101933:

> *“watch your case when using methods (POST and GET)...it must be always uppercase. in case of you write it in lower case it wont work.”*

Comment: That is perfect. ! +1

Comment: worked for me.... thnx