# sending post data via php file_get_contents doesnt work

Tags: php

i tried both solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606737/sending-post-data-along-with-file-get-contents), but seems to work not form me

my request is build like this:

```
<?php
class RequestObject {
  public $p1 = 1;
  public $p2 = 2;
}
$requestObject = new RequestObject();

$requestString = http_build_query($requestObject); 
  // ^^ returns 'p1=1&p2=2'

// $requestUrl = "http://address/api?fn=li_con"; // old with failure response
$requestUrl = "http://address/api/?fn=li_con";
$requestParameters = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header"  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "content" => $requestString
    )
);
$streamContext = stream_context_create($requestParameters);
$result = file_get_contents($requestUrl, false, $streamContext);
echo "$result";
```

my api makes a simple response of post and get array as json string:

```
<?php
switch(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fn')) {
    case 'li_con' :
      echo json_encode(array($_POST, $_GET));
      break;
    default: 
      echo "action not found";

}
```

all i get back is this string:

```
[[],{"fn":"li_con"}]
```

so, what is wrong? why do i not get the post parameters in my api?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The error must be somewhere else. Is this the exact code you are testing?

Comment: It is possible for php.ini to disable the ability for `file_get_contents()` to read from a URL. If you're having trouble with it, check whether this is the case. Also, if you're planning for your code to be used on unknown php servers, be aware that they might have this config setting in place and not be able to change it. If this means that you can't use `file_get_contents()`, then consider using Curl instead; it's more code, but generally more compatible. Another option is a third party library like Guzzle.

Comment: thanks for all the comments. the failure was a missing slash in the requested url. the correct one hast to be '''http://address/api/?fn=li_con'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small bug: add `;` on line `echo "action not found"`. It gave me error when testing.

Beside that, it is working fine in my local testing. I used PHP development server, and here is my result (I removed `div` tag):

```
[{"p1":"1","p2":"2"},{"fn":"li_con"}]
```

I am using Arch Linux with PHP 7.0.10. Maybe there is something wrong with your environment? Please mention you PHP version, Web Server and its config, and how do you test your client script.

Comment: thanks, the ; was a typing failure. but the failure was a missing / in the requested url. so it works now