# How server to server communication is done in php

Tags: php

I really would like to know how server to server POST is done in php.
The scenario is,

Im having some data stored in variable $data which I wanted to post to my clients server through the backend.

Is it done using cURL or is there other way server to server POSTing is done?Please help

Comment: yes `cURL` is the best way

Comment: cURL is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can also use `file_get_contents` with a custom context if cURL isn't available, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents

Comment: Is curl really secure in terms to server to server call.Is there anyway the data can be spoofed?

Comment: This does not depend on the library you use for HTTP, but on the protocol and transport layer encryption: `SSL/HTTPS` is what makes it secure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I nicked this code from another question here on StackOverflow I cannot find right now. This is posting between two php-files.

```
$host=//target host
$path=//path to post file;
$vars=//string to send
$fp=fsockopen($host,80,$errno,$errstr,2);
if(!$fp){
    $echo 'Connection failed';die;
    }
else{
    $out ="POST ".$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.="Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $out.="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out.="Content-Length: ".strlen($vars)."\r\n";
    $out.="Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    $out.=$vars."\r\n";
    $par=fwrite($fp,$out);
    fclose($fp);
   }
```

The advantage from this above `file_get_contents` is it doesn't wait for a response, because it kills the connection after the post. The disadvantage: you never know if the post is processed by the receiving end;