# Get HTML of page that is available after login

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I need to get HTML of page that is available only after log-in and then process the data with PHP or Javascript. I do have a login and password and I could even log-in manually, but then I need to to run some script on another server and get that HTML.

It is possible to achieve that (without any hacking techniques)?

Comment: what did you tried already? What is the login method (webpage, htaccess, ...)?

Comment: start here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2445332/724913 . Once you have posted your login to the correct page and are redirected , you can open the next page as logged in.

Comment: Florian, Im not sure what is the login method, how could I find it out? It is login on this page: http://partner.martinus.sk/index.php

Comment: There is a Firefox Plugin called "Tamper Data", with this you can snoop out the data that is transfered upon login. You want to look which POST variables are send to what page, with this information you can implement a curl script performing the login.

Comment: Hmm good to know - I'll try it, btw. I think link from @arkoak - stackoverflow.com/a/2445332/724913 could help me. Maybe this question could be closed.