# JSON decoding with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

How to decode the URL in javascript?

```
<?php $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=drove&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = utf8_decode($data);
        $obj = json_decode($data);

        echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text); //km
    ?>
```

I want to do the same thing with javascript.

Comment: nit pick: you're not decoding the url. you're decoding the content the url points at.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're intentions are here -- you want to perform the equivalent of *all* of the code you posted in pure JavaScript? If so, I would suggest simply making an AJAX request to the PHP file you already have. Or, look into jQuery and its `$.getJSON` method.

Comment: {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Drove, 52372 Kreuzau, Germany" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "London, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "570 km",
                  "value" : 570075
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 28 mins",
                  "value" : 23309
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

I just want to get this data but in javascript variables.

Comment: An extremely relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents

Comment: but i want this in javascript

Comment: If you are doing it in Javascript, why not use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DistanceMatrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use JSON.parse(yourdata);

```
 var jsonData =  JSON.parse(data);
 alert(jsonData.rows[0].elements[0].distance_test;
```