# Recaptcha V2.0 always returns bool(false)

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I have a problem with Recaptcha V2.0 always returning false or bool(false). It feels like it doesn't validate through the right keys, but I have quadruple checked the domains I added and the keys I am using in my code. Maybe I've just done something wrong code wise.

The HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="/php/emailCode.php">
        Your Name <label><input type="text" name="name"></label>
        <br/>
        Email Address <label><input type="text" name="email"></label>
        <br/>
        Message <label><textarea name="message"></textarea></label>
        <br />
        <div id="captcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
        <br />
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
    $secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $rsp  = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $ip);

    var_dump($rsp);
    $arr = json_decode($rsp);
    if($arr->success === true){
        $EmailFrom = "example@example.com";
        $EmailTo = "example@gmail.com";
        $Subject = $_POST['email'];
        $Name = $_POST['name'];
        $Message = $_POST['message'];

        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "Name: ";
        $Body .= $Name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Message: ";
        $Body .= $Message;
        $Body .= "\n";

        // send email
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
    }else{
        echo 'Failure';
    }

}
```

Also in the head I run this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('captcha', {
            'sitekey' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        });
    };
</script>
```

I literally have no clue why it would return false.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: json_decode doesn't give you true booleans, so === won't work as expected.

Comment: There is also a composer-installable library that looks easier than implementing this yourself https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: Jerry, thanks for that, but that doesn't explain why the response is always false

Comment: user49438 That is true, but I am also doing this for learning purposes, thus why I kind of what to implement this myself.

Comment: Can you please paste the contents of `var_dump($arr);` after `$arr = json_decode($rsp);`

Comment: @skrilled it's just NULL.
I also did var_dump($captcha) and it gave me the nice long string like it should.

Comment: It's been a long time, but for readers who are wondering why this doesn't work: it's because you're sending a `GET` request. You lack the stream context to support a `POST` request using the `file_get_contents` function. If you're wondering how to go about that, then [you can find your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

In recaptcha you have two keys:

**Site key**
Use this in the HTML code your site serves to users.

and

**Secret key**
Use this for communication between your site and Google. Be sure to keep it a secret.

### **So in my case the problem was that for some reason I used one key for both the client and the server side which is wrong. You have one key for the html form (client side) (which is SITE KEY) and another for the server side. (which is SECRET KEY)**

Go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list
and click your site 
and read "***Adding reCAPTCHA to your site***"

edit:
in your client side :

```
  .
  ..
  ...
  <div id="captcha" data-sitekey="SITE KEY"></div>
  ...
  ..
  .
```

in your server side :

```
.
..
...
$secret = "SECRET KEY";
...
..
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php include_once "recaptchalib.php";  ?> //library to be added
<form action='' method=''>
<input type="text" id="myphn" placeholder="Email/Username">
        <input type="Password" id="mypass" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ldd7AoUAAAAAGMNn1YkptZO7s9TY2xHe7nW45ma" id='recaptcha'></div>
//contains the key   
<input type='submit'>
</form>

 $response=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
    $secret = '6Ldd7AoUAAAAAGpSbJYqM9Tsh04NG_1vCPeRlFOe';

            $rsp=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response");
            $arr= json_decode($rsp,TRUE);
            if($arr['success'] == TRUE){
            //var_dump($rsp); die;
}else{ echo 'not done';
}
```

Comment: add library, required div, after posting the value will be in $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']