# How to forward POST into another framework

Tags: php, laravel, joomla

I'm replacing old legacy system (Joomla) with Laravel.

At the beginning we have some pages in old and some in new framework so I planned to allow user to login with Laravel authentication method and then forward the credentials to Joomla, so user would be logged in to both at once.

Currently I'm stuck with forwarding part, as I can't figure out how to send login POST variables to Joomla URL.

[code]

```
    $url         = 'www.test.dev/index.php/lv/login?task=user.login';
    $fields      = [
        'username' => $credentials['username'],
        'password' => $credentials['password']
    ];
    $ch          = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        http_build_query($fields));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

[/code]

Comment: You can do this with file_get_contents, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0):

Use curl or Guzzle to send your post request to the joomla app.

Comment: sending cURL request out from Laravel's authentication class doesn't work - nothing happens - url is not reached

Comment: Then you are not doing something right. Can you paste your code