# How can I pass an argument to a script as GET method?

Tags: php

I have this folder-structure:

```
\out
    \MakeAvatar.php
\root
    \include
        \Calculator.php
    \img
        \avatar
```

What's **`MakeAvatar.php`**? That's a script which gets a parameter *(like id)* and makes a avatar based on that parameter. Now I need to pass a argument (`$id`) from `Calculator.php` to `MakeAvatar.php`. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
$_GET['id'] = $id; // passing
file_put_contents("../img/avatar/".$id.".jpg", file_get_contents("../out/MakeAvatar.php"));
```

But it doesn't work. I mean the result is a unknown-image *(unclear)*.

[image]

When I open that image by a editor, it is containing the content of `MakeAvatar.php` (all its codes). So it seems the problem is *passing*.

---

**Note1:** If I put `MakeAvatar.php` into root and pass that argument like this then if works:

```
... file_get_contents("http://example.com/MakeAvatar.php?id=$id")
```

But as you see `MakeAatar.php` is out of root and I cannot use `http`. So how can I pass an argument without `http`?

Comment: If it is out of root, you can try using `file_get_contents` with it's full system directory path, like `/out/MakeAvatar.php`

Comment: Please stop asking variations of the same question. It's always the same answer.

Comment: @Barmar Please stop marking my questions as duplicate. Yes they have a identical concept, But in this question I really need a workaround.

Comment: You really need to learn how PHP and webservers work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `file_get_contents` is actually *reading* the file contents, rather than *executing* it.

You'll either have to `include` your file from `Calculator.php` or expose it to the HTTP server and do a local http request (eg. like `file_get_contents('http://localhost/path/to/your/MakeAvatar.php')` )

I'd recommend wrapping your important logic in the `MakeAvatar` file into a function, then `include`ing it and executing the function.

Answer (score 0):

If your public Web server directory is root, then you should make an entry point, e.g. `root/avatar.php`. Let's call it *controller*. In the controller you should use a class(let's call it a *model*) which has a method generating avatars.

Thus, your structure might look like the following:

**root/avatar.php**

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../out/MakeAvatar.php';
MakeAvatar::printPng($_GET);
```

**out/MakeAvatar.php**

```php
<?php
class MakeAvatar {
  public static function printPng(array $input) {
    $id = $input['id'];
    echo '... PNG data for $id here...';
  }
}
```

Also, I'd keep models in a directory like `classes` or `lib`; controllers - in `public/something`, and views in different directory such as `templates`.