# Troubleshoot PHP file_get_contents() POST with JSON body

Tags: php, json, rest

I can't figure out how to make my PHP script work and I'm not allowed to use debugging tools on the server or run it locally. Please help.

It is targeting an open data API ([Statistics Norway / SSB](https://www.ssb.no/)), specifically this one:

```
$url = "http://data.ssb.no/api/v0/no/table/08940";
```

The API is queried with POST and provides output according to posted message body which must be formatted as JSON.

I build the $body with a nested array in PHP, and the output of `json_encode($body, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` is provided below (truncated).

This runs just fine in the [SSB API Console](http://data.ssb.no/api/v0/no/console) as well as in Restlet Client.

```
{
    "query": [
        {
            "code": "UtslpTilLuft",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "code": "ContentsCode",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                    "UtslippCO2ekvival"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "code": "Tid",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                    "1990",
                    "1991"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "response": {
        "format": "json"
    }
}
```

Here is the script for the file_get_contents():

```
$json_body = json_encode($body);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'content' => $json_body
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$output = json_decode($file, true);
```

I have looked at the answers given in *[How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)*, tried to replace json_encode() with http_build_query() and http_build_query(json_encode()), experimented with different 'header' but print_r($output) gives me nothing.

Edit: I removed `$output = json_decode($file, true);` and now it prints the JSON array! Still need to figure out how to turn that into a PHP variable but how can I do that without json_decode...?

Edit 2: I figured out the data is actually not regular JSON, but [*JSON-STAT*](https://json-stat.org/), in the form of a unidimensional array. The proper call in the message body (response: format) is not "json" but "json-stat". With "json", the returned data was incompatible for json_decode().

Any tips on how to parse that to a regular associative array in PHP is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why post data you already have access to? You access `$output['variables'][0]['values'][0]` and the like. Do you understand Associative Arrays?

Comment: Hi there, not sure if I understand what you mean, I'm not a native English speaker. Do you mean why do I print_r($output)? That is to get an understanding of the structure of the data which is returned by the API. Next step is to access the various places in the array like you say.

Comment: Then just access them. If you need to do stuff to your database you don't need to post, just run MySQL queries with `mysqli` or `PDO`. You will have to learn how to use Arrays and Objects first, if you don't know how to do that already. You have to crawl before you can walk. You have to walk before you can run.