# issues trying to refresh OAuth token

Tags: php, rest, post, infusionsoft

I'm trying to refresh my infusionsoft token, using this guide from their documentation: https://developer.infusionsoft.com/authentication/#refresh-access-token

```
$url = "https://api.infusionsoft.com/token";
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$refresh_token = '';

$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
        "Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode($client_id. ":". $client_secret),
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
    'method'  => 'POST',
  )
);
```

Does anything jump out at you? I am also reaching out for help on Infusionsoft forums as well, but I was wondering if any of you have done this before.

Answer (score 1):

grant_type and other variables need to be send as post parameter, you are currently sending them as http headers.

Also done here: [How to post data in PHP using file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: This didn't fix the issue, but thanks for pointing me down the right track.
i now have:

    $jstr = array(
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
    );

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                     "Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode($client_id. ":". $client_secret),
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => json_encode($jstr)
        )
   );

I have a feeling the "Authorization:" tag is incorrect

Comment: well, what was the error ? did the answer solved your question or not ?

Comment: It's a 401 unauthorized error, actually (even though I'm confident that the client ID and secret are correct)