# Bad Request 400 uploading images to the imgur API

Tags: php, html, imgur

I want to upload some pictures with the imgur-API to imgur, but I am always getting an Error 400 Bad Request. Whats the issue?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg'])) {
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name']));
    $options = array('http'=>array(
            'method'=>"POST",
            'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer *MY_ACCESS_TOKEN*\n".
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'content'=>$image
    ));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
    $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);
}
?>

<h1>My Account</h1>
 <form action="upload-pb.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload a profile image:
    <input type="file" name="profileimg">
    <input type="submit" name="uploadprofileimg" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the endpoint for `/image` [here](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image), it needs a parameter of `image`. You're passing it in as `content`, and not properly encoded as `image`. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents), I borrowed how to properly upload content using `stream_context_create`/`file_get_contents`:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg'])) {
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name']));
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'image' => $image,
        )
    );
    $options = array('http'=>array(
            'method'=>"POST",
            'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer *MY_ACCESS_TOKEN*\n".
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'content' => $postdata
    ));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
    $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);
```

Comment: Also, consider skipping `base64_encode` all together. It will make uploads smaller, and should work uploading the binary file to imgur.