# Using Laravel as a simple REST

Tags: laravel, rest, api

So i'm trying to grab data from another url which could be something like:

[Random Generated Json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1)

I want to use my Laravel project, as the REST api, for this, meaning that it shouldnt be able to store data, locally, however i should be able to GET/POST something from some API endpoint within my application, however i'm a little bit confused on how to do this.

I've been googleling like i mad man but i can't figure out how to solve my issue.

Can someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this documentation https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/build-restful-api-in-laravel-58-exampleexample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam pointed already to Guzzle.
You can also use cURL if you don't want to use an external library.

```
    $headers = [
        'Accept: application/json'
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    ]);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === false) {
        throw new \Exception('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $jsonResult = json_decode($result);
```

I wrote a little wrapper for my own applications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a package like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Then, to consume an api endpoint from within your application, you can simply do something like the following, using the example of random json:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
$json = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is by using `json_decode(file_get_contents())`

See example :

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'), true);
```

And for POST requests you may refer to Pascal MARTIN answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2445332/6514992)