# reCaptcha v3 not giving me a response after submitting my form?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement reCaptcha v3 for my contact page, but reCaptcha isn't playing along. I'm completely new to reCaptcha. I've tried to implement by following the docs' example and tried to "mind the gap" with ChatGPT along the way, but I'm still stuck. It appears I'm not getting a response from reCaptcha:

[image: Image of errors]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Before anyone asks, yes, I do have the keys, just didn't include them here for security and all that. Yes, I do have a key set for my localhost (I'm using it right now).

Code:

```
<?php include "head.php" ?>
    <title>How to Vote 2024 | Contact </title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }
    </script>

</head>

<?php include "header.php"?>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Contact</h1>

        <p>
            If you want to bring a bug to my attention or perhaps you're a party rep that wants to add information to your party's page or even recommend a party to be added or
            maybe just give a compliment. Please contact me using the form below.
        </p>

        <form id="form" action="../model/emails.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptchaResponse" id="recaptchaResponse">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email Address:</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="youremailhere@example.com" maxlength="25"/>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name:</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Matthews" maxlength="25"/>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="your message here..." maxlength="255"></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="validate_captcha">

            <button type="submit"
                data-sitekey="" 
                data-callback='onSubmit' 
                data-action='submit' class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha">Send Message</button>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <small>This form is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.</small>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

</main>

<?php include "footer.php" ?>
```

```
<?php 
    // Handles the email workings from the contact form on the Contact page
    $errors = [];
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get and clean POST data
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : '';
        $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']) : '';
        
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        
        // Validate form fields
        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
        }
        
        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = 'Email is empty or invalid';
        }
        
        if (empty($message)) {
            $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
        }        
    
        // If no errors, send email
        if (empty($errors)) {
            // Recipient email address (replace with your own)
            $recipient = "lmao@gmail.com";
    
            // Additional headers
            $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

            $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'; // URL to the reCAPTCHA server
            $recaptcha_secret = ''; // Secret key
            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptchaResponse']; // Response from reCAPTCHA server, added to the form during processing
            echo '&response='.$recaptcha_response;
            $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url.'?secret='.$recaptcha_secret.'&response='.$recaptcha_response); // Send request to the server
            $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha); // Decode the JSON response
            if($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->score >= 0.5 && $recaptcha->action == "submit"){ // If the response is valid
                // run email send routine
                echo $recaptcha->success;
                echo $recaptcha->score;
                echo $recaptcha->action;
                mail($recipient, 'Contact Form Submission', $message, $headers);
                echo 'Your message was sent successfully.'; // Success message
            }else{
                echo $recaptcha->success;
                echo $recaptcha->score;
                echo $recaptcha->action;
                echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again later'; // Error message
            }
        } else {
            // Display errors
            echo "The form contains the following errors:<br>";
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo "- $error<br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Not a POST request, display a 403 forbidden error
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        echo "You are not allowed to access this page.";
    }
?>
```

Page in question:
[image: Image of my form]

Comment: Do some simple debugging then. `var_dump($recaptcha);` to see what if actually contains - that would be a good start.

Comment: Just noticed that as per https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify, you must send a POST request to verify the recaptcha response, but your `file_get_contents` call will send a GET. Therefore it's perhaps not surprising that Google doesn't respond as you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents should help you to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to how you're handling the reCAPTCHA response. The error messages you're receiving `(Undefined property stdClass: $score and Undefined property stdClass: $action)` suggest that the properties score and action are not present or accessible within the response object.

The reCAPTCHA response should contain properties such as success to indicate whether the verification was successful, score which represents the confidence level of the user, and action which denotes the action the user performed.

Try below code if it works otherwise you need to debug their response,

```
$recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptchaResponse'];
$recaptcha_secret = 'YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'; // Replace with your actual secret key
$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_data = [
    'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
    'response' => $recaptcha_response
];

$recaptcha_options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($recaptcha_data)
    ]
];
$recaptcha_context = stream_context_create($recaptcha_options);
$recaptcha_result = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url, false, $recaptcha_context);
$recaptcha_data = json_decode($recaptcha_result);
if ($recaptcha_data->success && $recaptcha_data->score >= 0.5 && $recaptcha_data->action === 'submit') {
    // Your code to send the email
    mail($recipient, 'Contact Form Submission', $message, $headers);
    echo 'Your message was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
}
```

Comment: Did you use AI to generate this answer? It has a lot of the hallmarks. Doing that is specifically banned by stackoverflow. You can use it to make a draft answer but you would need verify the content and edit it - usually to make it more specific. At the moment this suggests generic debugging steps rather than actually solving anything.