# Passing cookies from a page to another in php (or javascript)

Tags: php, cookies

Hullo,
I need to open a page with file_get_html featuring it with two cookies a get from another page. How do I collect the cookies from the former page and submit them to the latter?

Comment: You don't have to pass cookies like querystring. You just read cookie value. Am I missing something?

Comment: there is no problem in passing the cookies through curl in php, suppose u are calling some API, which needs cookies to find your user_id, then u have to pass it as cookies in the api call

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers on how to pass cookies through file_get_contents

Comment: Ok, I found the solution by using curl by saving the cookies in a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if your working with cookies the best is to set the cookie on a Domain base:

So lets say your domain is www.somesite.com

//This cookie will expire in one hour.

> $expire=time()+3600; 
>   setcookie("user", $value, $expire, "/","somesite.com");

Now to read the cookie on another page with the same domain

> echo $_COOKIE["user"];

If you want to test your cookies better in your browser i recommend you use firefox with firebug and firecookie addons in that way you will see all your cookies and you can even edit them and understand the way they work on a browser.

To download firefox: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/fx/

To get the firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

To get the firecookie: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/

Better not to use cookies if the data is sensitive as the cookie can be manipulated from the client side... if you want to secure more the data you can use combination of cookie and session.

Regards,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript first:

As JavaScript is a client side language, so there is no need to pass the cookies, but if you are calling a URL of some different domain then you have to use [jquery.getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), as cross domain is not allowed in javascript

Second in PHP, you can pass the cookies through curl, there is a operation in curl which is `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie)`. At any time you can get the cookies by `$_COOKIE`.