# What's the common practice to invoke a JSON call in PHP?

Tags: php, json, rpc

I'm trying to make a JSON call library. It has the following features.

- be able to customize the header
- be able to POST any data to server(including form-encoding (`a=1&b=2&c=3`) and JSON data chunk)
- parse the response and return as a JSON object

I searched in other questions and found that there are only two answers.

- use `file_get_contents()`.  This way is pretty simple and easy to use; however, you cannot do anything more than get the content -- you cannot add headers, cannot use POST. But it is usually supported by all servers.
- use curl. This way seems powerful and you can do nearly everything with it.  The disadvantage is that you have to install libcurl and php-curl support on your server, which means you may not use it on servers that have no curl installed.

So, if I want to develop a common library that can be used on most server, is `curl` a good choice?

Is there any other ways to do this?

---

In a short word, I'm looking for a PHP version of `urllib2` in python - easy to use, powerful, and reliable.

Comment: curl is a fine choice. It is very widely installed, and very often available as an optional install for managed or hosted systems.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I still remember those painful days when I found my hosting provider did't install curl on my virtual server. So I'm not really sure that curl is widely installed...

Comment: You *can* add headers to `file_get_contents` but using cURL is much more preferred, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers

Comment: Thanks @BurningtheCodeigniter. I didn't know that `file_get_contents` can be used in that way. However, as you said, cURL looks much better.

Comment: you can POST also - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents/2445332#2445332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [HTTP stream context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). Both can accomplish what you have described; `curl` *might* not be installed everywhere, while stream contexts are a core feature and are always available.

Actually, you can also implement your library using [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), which would be more work but will probably allow you greater control if you need to do weirder things with your requests.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using sockets except as a very last resort, as there are lots of details to the HTTP protocol (e.g. chunked encoding, redirects), and you'll have to reinvent lots of wheels.

Answer (score -1):

As i know, curl is included in mostly on many server, since it supported from 4.0.2 PHP version natively.
Also there is a native php function [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), which customizes your response's headers by simply using like this -> `header('location: index.php')`, `header('cache-control: ok')` and so on. You can view Network Functions section on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.network.php)

Comment: Thank you.  It seems curl is a good choice.  `header()` has nothing to  me, since I want to fetch content from other server, but not to give content to others.