# Setting up a custom payment module for opencart

Tags: php, module, opencart, payment

I'm trying to connect a custom payment module for opencart. Now I have a form that sends all the info collected from the user to a URL something like...

```
<form action="https://www.mywebsite.com/paymentProcessor.php" type="post">

<input type="text" name="userName">
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="text" name="Amount">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm">

</form>
```

Now paymentProcessor.php checks all information provided and returns "YES" or "NO" if the transaction was successful or not respectively then it sends that information back to the callback function in opencart. Now here is the problem , How does paymentProcessor.php send the information to the callback function? What code do i need to include on paymentProcessor.php to set the variable and how does the callback function receive the variables. Any solution in json or anything else will be highly appreciated. thx

Comment: Usually there is normal request from `paymentProcessor` back to Your `callback` by sending back all the sent information (for You to check that they were not edited - if yes, the payment is not valid) + the information about the payment itself... This request could be done using `cURL`, `file_get_content`, `fsock_open` or other streaming. `file_get_content` is the easiest way while `cURL` gives You plenty of control over the request. And usually the whole requests (both ways) are encoded using secret key so that they cannot be read/modified...

Comment: Thanks a bunch @shadyyx . U r a life saver. I managed to use file_get_contents() and it works like a charm. thx

Comment: OK, I'll post my comment as an answer so that You can accept it and mark the question as answered... But I recommend using `cURL` - though a little more lines are needed to do a request but You have more control over it.

Comment: NOTED.  I'll try and read more about curl. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there is normal request from `paymentProcessor` back to Your callback by sending back all the sent information (for You to check that they were not edited - if yes, the payment is not valid) + the information about the payment itself...

This request could be done using `cURL`, `file_get_contents`, `fsock_open` or other streaming. `file_get_contents` is the easiest way while `cURL` gives You plenty of control over the request. And usually the whole requests (both ways) are encoded using secret key so that they cannot be read/modified...

I recommend using `cURL` for better control over the request though using `file_get_contents` You can do almost the same using [stream headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers) ([PHP doc + example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2351))...