# file_get_contents on times out when run on same server as target

Tags: php

If I put in my php file:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/myPage.php");
```

If I run this script on example.com, the page eventually times out.  If I run the same script on a different server, it loads correctly immediately.  I checked and allow_url_fopen is 'On' in phpinfo().  Any ideas what this could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check to make sure that the system can correctly resolve to it's self. Try this from the command line: `curl http://www.example.com/myPage.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use [this class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

for getting things DOM from a URL

Like

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");
echo $html;
```

Comment: That class also uses file_get_contents() so it runs into the same problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the webpage with chrome/firebug in the network tab.
see what headers you are sending.

Make a new file_get_contents with the same headers.

[See here how to send headers along with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers)

This will be like actually opening the website and thus should work just fine.