# HTTP headers sent by PHP

Tags: php, curl, header, file-get-contents

I am using CURL and file_get_contents to find out the basic difference between a server request for a page and a browser request (organic).

I am requesting for a PHPINFO page both ways and found that it is giving different output in different cases.

For example, when I am using a browser the PHPINFO shows this:
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   no-cache
This info is missing when I am requesting the same page through PHP.

My CURL:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $testIP);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

My file_get_contents:

```
$opts = array(
'socket' => array('bindto' => 'xxx.xx.xx.xx:0'),
'method'  => 'GET',
'user_agent '  => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0", // this doesn't work
'header' => array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8')
);
```

My goal:
    To make a PHP request look identical to a browser request.

Comment: Why do you want your requests to look like browser requests?

Comment: @Halcyon This is to prevent servers from treating my requests differently from a regular browser request.

Comment: Ok, pretend I ask you _'why?'_ 5 times, then decide if that's really what you want to do.

Comment: @Halcyon I need help to complete this project. I'll ask 'why' to my boss after the project is complete.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a good solution. And the reason there isn't a good solution is because you shouldn't be doing this. If you're writing a crawler people are going to want to know you're crawling their site. It's deceitful to say you are someone or something you are not.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers

Comment: @Halcyon before you call the police I must assure you that this is an intranet project where our NY based server will interact with our Seattle based server. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Halcyon a browser is unable to save many pages but a PHP request can. That's our primary purpose i.e. to save data which we can't do manually. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's a great reference. Quite helpful. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I'm perplexed. Why would you do it this way? You can design a web service API and do away with all this nonsense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

one of possible ways for server to detect you are a php code not a browser is check your cookie. with php curl request to the server once and inject the cookie you get to your next request.
check here :
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_04.htm
one other way that server can understand you are a robot(php code) is check referer http header.
you can learn more here :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer