# How to get latest commit date - Github API

Tags: javascript, php, github-api

I'm currently writing a small database of git reps and im wondering how i would go ahead and get the date of the latest commit if i have the rep listed in my database.

I've never worked with the github API and im having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around it.

If anyone could help me figure it out i'd much appreciate it. PHP or JS prefereably as all the examples ive found has been in ruby.

Comment: This is the api you'll be using.  Can you show what you have tried, and explain what didn't work?  https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

Comment: Github has what it's called, a "RESTful API", for the kind of which many tutorials exist online - If you don't know how to poll such services it's best if you take a tutorial that teaches the fundamentals of making such requests

Comment: This is what ive tried:

$url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/epenance/hoberthovers';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

What im getting back is: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: You will need to execute: `curl -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo>/commits`

Comment: Aight, it works on my live server but not my localhost with what i wrote above, however some of the links in my db dives into their folders which is the ones i want to see the update on such as this: 

https://github.com/ikkeflikkeri/LeagueSharp/tree/master/EasyAhri

So my previous line doesnt work. 

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to use PHP like [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845346/how-to-get-latest-commit-date-github-api#comment47817188_29845346), I'd use [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) instead of [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), as you'd need to configure [allow-url-fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

GitHub also requires you to send a `user-agent` in the header: https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required

For example, your PHP code would look like;

```php
$objCurl = curl_init();

//The repo we want to get
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/google/blueprint/commits");

//To comply with https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "StackOverflow-29845346"); 

//Skip verification (kinda insecure)
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Get the response
$response = curl_exec($objCurl);
print_r( json_decode($response, true) );
```

<sup>**Note:** You will be able to continue using `file_get_contents` and send the `user-agent` header. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107792/3000179)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, how would i navigate the json object in php since its not an array?

Comment: Remove `, true` from `json_decode` to make it an object.

Comment: I needed to add ````curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);```` to stop curl from automatically outputting the response. ````$response=1```` prior to this addition.

Comment: please update your code !!!!
```$aCommit = json_decode($sInfo, false);
$sTimeLatest = $aCommit[0]->commit->author->date;
$iTimeLatest = strtotime($sTimeLatest);``` i wasted 15 minutes before reading these comments here !

Answer (score 10):

Old question but I wanted to point out (at least with api v3) you could use the branches api to get the latest commit date for a particular branch. I assume in your case you're interested in master.

Which would look like:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/master
```

See https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/

Comment: maybe obvious, but your repo must be public for the github api to access it through a simple fetch request.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to answer this exact question so I made a very small demo of how to get the date of the latest commit.

[Demo](https://latest-commit.ta-dachi.now.sh/)

Output:

```
ta-dachi
master
2019-03-21T14:50:22Z <----- What you want
b80126c3ea900cd7c92729e652b2e8214ff014d8
https://github.com/ta-dachi/eatsleepcode.tech/tree/master
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/ta-dachi/latest-commit)

index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>React Local</title>
  <script
    type="application/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="application/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="application/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="application/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@3.0.0/dist/fetch.umd.js"
  ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="index.jsx"></script>
</body>
```

index.jsx

```
/**
 * See https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch
 *
 * Example Github api request:
 * https://api.github.com/repos/ta-dachi/eatsleepcode.tech/branches/master
 */
class LatestCommitComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      author: "",
      branch: "",
      date: "",
      sha: "",
      link: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Replace this with your own repo
    // https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/master
    fetch(
      "https://api.github.com/repos/ta-dachi/eatsleepcode.tech/branches/master"
    )
      .then(response => {
        response.json().then(json => {
          console.log(json);
          this.setState({
            author: json.commit.author.login,
            branch: json.name,
            date: json.commit.commit.author.date,
            sha: json.commit.sha,
            link: json._links.html
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.author}</div>
        <div>{this.state.branch}</div>
        <div>{this.state.date}</div>
        <div>{this.state.sha}</div>
        <div>{this.state.link}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LatestCommitComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```