# How to retrieve the list of git repositories which were updated recently

Tags: git

How to retrieve the list of git repositories which were updated recently (say from last 1 day or 2 days or a week or a month) within my organization. I would prefer to do this search based on the organization_id

Comment: Do you want to do this on git**hub** or anything else?

Comment: Also, do you want to do this in a specific programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

- [list repositories in your organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)

  ```
  https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos
  ```
- for each repo, [get the latest commit date of, for instance, the `master` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47719120/6309)

  ```
  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/master
  ```

Comment: Once you have `GET /...` and once you have just a URL. That might be confusing.

Comment: How do you still filter the above list based on the recently updated repositories

Comment: @Rpj Using https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch on each repo, you have the date of the last committer: you can sort on that date.

Comment: I was thinking if there was a simpler way to just list the repositories which changed in the last week across any branch not just the master