# PHP: how to use HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING to pass gzip acceptance when using fileget_contents()?

Tags: php

I'm downloading once a day a large json output emitted wy a my webapi.
My api server can output using gzip encoding, but it checks if to do this testing if HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING contains the word 'gzip'.

From webserver with the client script, I use file_get_content to read the json. But how to warn the api server that i'm able to accept gzip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can send headers (e.g. the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING header) with your `file_get_contents()` request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers).

An alternative could be using cURL to send the request with custom headers.