# file_get_contents returns nothing on html input

Tags: php, web-crawler, file-get-contents

file_get_contents() returns proper file contents on [www.akaar.org](http://www.akaar.org) but not on [www.ptsda.org](http://www.ptsda.org).

The main difference is that [akaar.org](http://akaar.org) is a php project and [ptsda.org](http://ptsda.org) is html.

Basically I am building a web crawler in php. It didn't crawl through that particular site, when I successfully crawled through at least 150+ sites.

Comment: So i understood that there is a security in their server.
But I have got an idea now, Is there a way to save the file and pass it to my php crawler? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

I saved the page as a HTML and gave input to my php crawler.

```
<?php

     $contents = file_get_contents("The downloaded HTML file");
     print_r($contents);
?>
```

SUCCESS :)

Thanks to all for replying.

Answer (score 2):

ptsda.org is returning this 403 (forbidden) error:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action
```

So it looks like they have Apache ModSecurity protection in place to stop their content from being scraped in this way.

Comment: So is there anyway I could?

Answer (score 2):

Here the reason why certain websites doesn't allow to crawl.

1. `file_get_contents('http://www.akaar.org/')` You can get result from website, which means the server where this website is hosted is not configured filewall to block crawl requests.
2. `file_get_contents('http://www.ptsda.org/')` In this case you will get `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity` as output, which means the server is configured with Firewall and you won't get the response. Read more about [ModSecurity](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/what-is-modsecurity-and-why-is-it-important).

Here is the solution, try to use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Note: This is a work around.

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.ptsda.org/');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ptsda');
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    //print_r($query);
?>
```

Comment: So is there anyway I could?

Comment: Did it work for u? It didnt for me. 
And also see I hav updated my question. Thank u..

Comment: uncomment //print_r($query); and try again. You will get output.

Comment: Yea obviously, I tried. First i tried with my crawler, then in a separate file as well.
It didnt work.

Comment: Nothin on screen. And found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the host of ptsda.org is returning this 403 (Forbidden) error:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.ptsda.org"): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity
```

This shows they have protection in place to stop their content from being crawled by bots. You *might* be able to bypass this, by setting a useragent string within PHP ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107792/2801767)).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ptsda.org/

Is a flash site, which cannot be crawled that easily as HTML would
[image]