# How to make file_get_contents session aware?

Tags: php, http, web, backend

I have a php script that will make a series of requests on a server. The first request will be a login request.

The problem is that `file_get_contents` seems to create a new session every time, so how can I make it session aware?

Here is my function which needed to make it remember session:

```
function request($method, $data, $url){
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"."Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n",
            'method'  => $method,
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    session_write_close();
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Should be obvious: By passing the existing session id … // This would probably be easier if you used cURL instead, because that has means for proper cookie handling across requests on board already.

Comment: With lots of effort. Keep and extract the `$http_response_header` to repopulate the request [context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers) with the according session cookie.

Comment: @mario but this is an html pages not an api

Comment: @CBroe please check my code above

Comment: And how is that relevant? Why does your code assume the local session_id() and name to be identical to the remote one?

Comment: As @mario said, you of course need to use the session name and id the remote server returns, not your local ones. And to get those, you need to extract them from the response headers of your first request, that starts the session on the remote server. Again: _Much_ easier with cURL.

Comment: @CBroe can you post how can I do it with curl?

Comment: No, please go research that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I just used curls instead of file_get_contents and everything works well with me:

```
function request_url($method='get', $vars='', $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. I could see this helping a lot of newcomers. Thanks for posting your findings!

Comment: For an explanation of why this answer works, please read [this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35488860/2982225)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of why the cookies work in cURL in [Hazem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460855/2982225).

### [Author:](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11304370) [Nate I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293325/nate-i)

The magic happens with `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` tells cURL to write all internally known Cookies to the specified file. In this case, 'cookies/cookies.txt'. For most users, it's generally recommended to use something like `tempnam('/tmp', 'CURLCOOKIES')` so you know for sure that you can generate this file.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` tells cURL which file to use for Cookies during the cURL request. That's why we set it to the same file we just dumped the Cookies to.