# file_get_contents Google Search w/ Styles

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, google-search

I'm creating a site that gets a google search and changes all the answer titles to No One Cares.

It is doing this by getting the file contents of the google search query and appending some JQuery to change the titles, all is working.

However, the file_get_contents produces the old style google results:
http://cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/NoOneCaresGoogle/?q=Test

Unlike the modern google results:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Test

Is there anyway, via the url query or otherwise in PHP to get the modern styles?

*I assume it is to do with the google servers being unable to detect a browser verison?*

Comment: Test it by passing a proper user agent string if you suspect that solves it.

Comment: @PeeHaa Any idea how I do that? My assumption was a random guess.

Comment: It's just a search away... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers

Comment: @PeeHaa Thank you, it appears to have worked, I copied my current user agent in, and now it has the newer styles. Thanks.