# Getting question mark when i'm sending arabic sms

Tags: php

Can somebody help me why am I getting question mark when I'm sending arabic alphabets?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 1 
     ) 
));

$fra = $_GET["f"];
$til = explode('-',$_GET["t"]);
$text = urlencode($_GET['m']);
foreach($til as $til ) {
    file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/api/sendSms.php?
        apiKey=xxxxxxxxx&charset=UTF-8&senderId=$fra&mobile=$til&message=$text", 0, $ctx
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you see these? What are you using to send and receive?

Comment: endpoint api provide this type of language?

Comment: when i receiving the sms.

Comment: @daremachine have any idea?

Comment: try send request and specify language in headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers