# Very long (10+ seconds) response time on file_get_contents() call for Instagram content

Tags: php, instagram, file-get-contents, php-7.1

I'm troubleshooting someone's code that's designed to dynamically fetch pictures from Instagram, then print them on a page.

Problem being, the process itself is basically bottlenecking their entire page, causing a 10-12 second spike in load time.

I can't seem to find what in particular is causing this issue. Previous Googling has led me to responses about the connection not being closed automatically when using file_get_contents(), but that shouldn't be an issue as of PhP 5.6, and especially not 7.1, should it?

This is the code in question:

```
<?php

function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
  $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/');
  $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
  $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]);
  $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
  return $insta_array;
}

$tag = "placeholder";
$results_array = scrape_insta_hash($tag);

$limit = 5;
$imgs = array();

for ($i=$limit; $i >= 0; $i--) {                  
  if(array_key_exists($i,$results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"])) {
    $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"][$i]["node"];
    $newPosting = ["image"=>$latest_array['display_url']];
    $imgs[] = $newPosting['image'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You might be throttled by Instagram servers if you're sending to many requests consecutively. Try faking a browser request because Instagram probably flags you as a bot, take a look at this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers) and if you're scrapping in a loop, which I suspect you are, try adding a small sleep in between requests.

Comment: Thank you - after your comment about scraping in a loop and being throttled as a result, I tried to load the code on a site that hadn't requested anything from Instagram in a while - and sure enough, no throttling the first few times, then a hard throttle.

What would be the solution for a use case like this? Set up a cache with the output from file_get_contents(), or?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you confirmed my suspicions in your comment, so this is what I would do:

First I would adjust the **scraping** method to mimic a browser request. Try playing around with headers and add more if necessary.

```
<?php

function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
  $opts = [
     "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.109\r\n"
         ]
  ];

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/', false, $context);
  file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/');
  $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
  $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]);
  $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
  return $insta_array;
}
```

Because the way you were getting the page Instagram would register you as a php bot.

Then in the part of code where you are making the request in a loop add a small timeout:

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $res = scrape_insta_hash($tag);
    ...

    // Sleep for half a second
    usleep(500000);
}
```

Also try playing around with the sleep number to see what is the lowest value you can put. I mean there is no exact answer here, you'll need a lot of trial and error to go around Instagram's throttling mechanism.

Also what could be useful is using different IP adresses, maybe the moment you get throttled you could use some VPN as a proxy and change the IP address.

As you mentioned, a caching mechanism is not a bad idea as well, but you'd need a way to figure out if the page changed, because at the first glance I don't see any headers that could be useful, per Instagram's response headers this page is never cached, there is no etags nothing really you could use as a check.

Comment: Hey! I've tried to add both the header change in calls and a usleep in the loop itself now, though it appears to have had little effect. I went and fetched an API access token as well, just in case it was an issue of anonymous requests being throttled. There doesn't appear to have been any change in page load time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I updated to PHP 7. **file_get_contents()** Had amazing speed in PHP 5 but sucks at PHP 7. I solved the issue by using **curl()** instead. You should try that too.