# Call a function with curl inside a loop on php

Tags: php, curl, foreach

I need to loop and inside I need to call curl through a function. How do I call this function without losing performance (decrease script execution time which is around 2.23 sec)? Thanks.

```
foreach ($token_values as $token) {
    $cards[] = array_merge(array('CardToken' => $token), getCards($merchantId, $merchantKey, $token));
}

function getCards($merchantId, $merchantKey, $token){
   $ch = curl_init('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/1/card/'.$token);
   $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'MerchantId: ' . $merchantId, 'MerchantKey: ' . $merchantKey);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Comment: `without losing performance?` <- how is performance being currently lost?

Comment: "Without losing performance" = decrease script execution time which is around 2.23 sec

Comment: how many rows are you looping?

Comment: no more than two or three

Comment: have you pinged the server from CLI to make sure it's not (their)server-side?

Comment: Yes, no problem was found. min=34ms; max=183ms

Comment: Can you test it with file_get_contents instead? Just to make sure that it is not curl library's fault? (clear instructions can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers )

Comment: Move to curl_multi to process the requests in parallel.