# User agent with file get contents in PHP without Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-get-contents, user-agent

I am trying to change user agent in header while using `file_get_contents`

Code 1 With Array (Working fine) :

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: <signature>"
        )
    )
);

echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/", false, $context);
```

Code 2 :

```
$context = ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/", false, $context);
```

Code 3 :

```
$context = ini_set('User-Agent: <signature>');
echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/", false, $context);
```

I am looking to change user agent without `array` and using `User-Agent: <signature>`

Comment: `ini_set` would be for the current project and won't create any new impact on `https://www.example.com/`

Comment: You need to show a minimum reproducible code for this, else the marked duplicate is sufficient.

Comment: @nice_dev my question is not copy. i am trying to add user agent

Comment: You can refer this answer on the same dupe https://stackoverflow.com/a/13969212/4964822

Comment: @nice_dev i know it work but i am trying without array.

Comment: Why **exactly** do you need a solution without an array? As the argument to `stream_context_create` **has** to be an array by definition of that function, I don't see any chance not to use an array