# How can I use Simple Html DOM Library in PHP to return html content from Skroutz?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I downloaded the Simple Html DOM library files, and using this piece of code on top of my `.php` file I managed to call the [simple_html_dom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom/) file ( note that I am running this on a server thus I used the built in php function [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to call the directory of the project's folder ).

*CODE*:

```
<?php
$hard_path = getcwd().'/';
require_once "$hard_path".'simple_html_dom.php';
```

Moving on I am interested in `returning` or `echoing` the html content of this URL, `https://www.skroutz.gr/s/36232462/Asus-TUF-Dash-F15-FX516PC-HN004W-15-6-FHD-144Hz-i7-11370H-16GB-512GB-SSD-GeForce-RTX-3050-W11-Home-US-Keyboard.html?from=home_price_drops`.

*PROBLEM*:

To simply `echo` the html content of the url, I used the Simple HTML DOM's library function called [file_get_html()](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/file_get_html/). But when I use the code below to echo the content of the page I get no output( note that this happens only with `skroutz.gr` wepsite links and incase I use a different link for example from wikipedia or any other site in general I do get content in the output of my `.php` file ). Also there are no errors being returned.

*code*:

```
$dom = file_get_html('https://www.skroutz.gr/s/36232462/Asus-TUF-Dash-F15-FX516PC-HN004W-15-6-FHD-144Hz-i7-11370H-16GB-512GB-SSD-GeForce-RTX-3050-W11-Home-US-Keyboard.html?from=home_price_drops');
echo $dom;
```

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
<?php
$hard_path = getcwd().'/';
require_once "$hard_path".'simple_html_dom.php';

$dom = file_get_html('https://www.skroutz.gr/s/36232462/Asus-TUF-Dash-F15-FX516PC-HN004W-15-6-FHD-144Hz-i7-11370H-16GB-512GB-SSD-GeForce-RTX-3050-W11-Home-US-Keyboard.html?from=home_price_drops');
echo $dom;
```

*QUESTIONS*:

- Why am I not getting any output when I try to read skroutz.gr's weblinks?
- Are there any mistakes in my code that I should be aware of?

*Thanks in advance for your time and effort!*

Comment: _"Why am I not getting any output when I try to read skroutz.gr's weblinks?"_ - probably because that site does not want you to rip their content in such ways, and has implemented measures against it. Sending a User-Agent mimicking a current browser is one of the simpler things that can sometimes help, but it really depends on the specific site.

Comment: Hello @CBroe , Thanks for the advice, could you provide a link about the `Sending a User-Agent mimicking a current browser`?

Comment: You can do that via the `context` parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers