# For some reason file_get_contents stopped working from one day to another and returns a "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable" error in PHP 7.2.34

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

## THE PROBLEM

I am mantaining a webpage that's running in a **server hosted by Inmotion** and using **PHP 7.2.34.** Let's call it "https://company-website.net/"

Inside this page we need to read a JSON file. The file for sure is there, one can go to the url and open it and the JSON file is located in "https://company-website.net/locale.json"

And from one day to another, on **January 10th 2024**, **file_get_contents suddenly returned this php error**:

> file_get_contents(https://company-website.net/locale.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

The code looked like this:

```
$fileUrl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/locale.json';
$file = file_get_contents($fileUrl);
```

## I tried something else

I tried setting an Accept header like it said on this stack overflow thread (just changed Accept-Language: en for Accept: */*:
[PHP file_get_contents() and setting request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers)

So, the code ended like this:

```
$fileUrl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/locale.json';
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Accept: */*"
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($fileUrl, false, $context);
```

But nothing

## THE SOLUTION IN THE END

Then I ended up changing file get contents for curl, as mentioned in this thread:
[PHP file_get_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

so it ended up like this:

```
$fileUrl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/locale.json';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $fileUrl);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Company Name');
$file = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

**AND IT WORKED**.

But still I'm baffled as to WHY it stopped working form one day to the other, not sure if it has something to do with PHP deprecation, with Inmotion changing something security wise, really lost here. I still want to try and use file_get_contents and understand what the issue could be. If anyone can give any insight, I'd be more than thankful.

Comment: If this is a static file, then what is first and foremost baffling here, is why on earth would you request it via HTTP in the first place ... Read it via the file system, instead of adding the absolutely unnecessary _overhead_ of making an HTTP request.

Comment: I want to understand the difference you mention between using the file system and http request. I understand http request is via curl and file system is using file_get_contents, am I wrong? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php
If that's the case, then I would like to know what's the best practice here.

Comment: cURL makes HTTP requests, but file_get_contents can do both. It's _primary_ purpose is to read from the file system - hence the name; but using the HTTP wrapper, it can also make HTTP requests (if the config option allow_url_fopen is set to true.) And you read from the file system, by _not_ specifying an HTTP URL as the first parameter, but a local file system path. Easiest to use a full absolute path - `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/locale.json'` should most likely do the trick in this instance.

Comment: `file system is using file_get_contents, am I wrong`...yes you're wrong. If you give file_get_contents a _URL_, it'll send a HTTP request. If you give it a filesystem path, it'll open the file. This is explained in the documentation. And it also should be clear to you that your own file_get_contents code was making a HTTP request, since you were getting HTTP status codes back as the response, and the error message even says `HTTP request failed`! Obviously such an error cannot come from opening a file via the filesystem. So, quite honestly, I'm not sure how you came to ask that question.

Comment: `what's the best practice`..."best practice" is a purely subjective and opinionated term. There's no such thing, in reality. You can do whatever works best for your situation. If there is no meaningful difference (for your purposes) between two approaches then you should use whatever your preference is.

Comment: But clearly, since HTTP requests are less efficient than direct filesystem access, then given the choice the filesystem access would be a better option, because it's quicker and uses less system resources.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I learned a lot from your comments. Didn't know file_get_contents would make an http request if given an url. Thanks to both of you for the insights and your time!

Comment: `Didn't know file_get_contents would make an http request if given an url`...well like I said, it was self-evident from what you were reporting as the result of trying to run your code!

Comment: @ADyson "Obviously such an error cannot come from opening a file via the filesystem. So, quite honestly, I'm not sure how you came to ask that question" It came from me not understanding and not knowing file_get_contents could do this kind of behaviour, I thought we could do http requests and nothing more. And as you say, another fail of mine was not reading the documentation in its entirety. So I thank you for your comment for helping me understand this. Thanks

Comment: But what I mean is, when your error message says "HTTP request failed" then clearly it's making a HTTP request, whether or not you already knew it could do that :-)

Comment: Yeah. I'm failing to say here that I didn't know we had the option of NOT doing an http request. I thought it was the only way to read a JSON file. Again, documentation! I'll read it better next time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using PHP 7.2.34

The biggest difference between `file_get_contents` and `curl` in PHP 7 is that `file_get_contents` defaults to using http/1.0, while `curl` uses http/1.1. Based on the returned 406 error, I believe it is highly likely that this is the reason. (Don't feel strange, even if your request is sent with http/1.0, the server can response an http/1.1 error, see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/442960/nginx-ignoring-clients-http-1-0-request-and-respond-by-http-1-1))

Additionally, your curl code has added UA, which may be another issue.

Try to add these two items to the context:

```
"protocol_version" => "1.1"
"user_agent" => "Company Name"
```

Comment: Tried adding those to the context for file_get_content but same result as before, 406. Context now was:
`$context = stream_context_create($opts, array ('protocol_version'=> '1.1', 'user_agent' => 'Company Name'));`

Comment: Put them in `$opts['http']`

Comment: Didn't know there would be a difference. It works! Thanks a lot! I already touched some stuff a bit and it only needs an User-Agent, like so:`"header" => "User-Agent: Company Name"`. I'm defaulting it back to how it was. Again, thanks a lot, shingo!!

Answer (score 1):

**In the end if you are interested in reading a file using a http request**, as [shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) said, is adding one of 2 elements to the header, in my case it was adding an User-Agent, even if it's anything. So the code ended up like this:

```
$fileUrl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/locale.json';
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "User-Agent: Company Name"
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($fileUrl, false, $context);
```

And it's working once more without the need of using curl. :)

*ON THE OTHER HAND*
The real issue was me not understanding that I could look up the file without having to input an URL to file_get_contents. I thought it would be the same, I have learned now that using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of `'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` enables file_get_contents to read the file without an http request (as the path given is not pointing to an https url). All of this thanks to and mentioned by .
[ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) and [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe). The code would then have to be:

```
$fileUrl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/locale.json';
$file = file_get_contents($fileUrl, false, $context);
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you've used a HTTP request at all here, since the JSON file appears to be on the same server as the PHP script. Direct filesystem access should be possible, and will be more performant.

You could try something like:

```
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/locale.json';
$file = file_get_contents($filepath);
```