How to get OAuth Access Tokens via HTTP header?
I've been using the Battle.Net API for years, but last week Blizzard made a change and I have no idea how to get it working. (Why break something that's not broken...)
This is what they wrote:

It will no longer be permissible to pass OAuth Access Tokens via the
URL query string. Instead, these tokens must be included in the HTTP
header of the request:
e.g. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_TOKEN

I have no idea what's this.
I'll show you my code and I hope you can help me out.
function getToken() {
        $client_id = 'CLIENT ID';
        $client_secret = 'CLIENT SECRET';
        $url = "https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token";
        $params = ['grant_type'=>'client_credentials'];
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id.':'.$client_secret);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result->access_token;
    }
    //call OAUTH2 function and set it to $token var
    $token = getToken();

After this I request all the Battlegrounds cards and add them to my database. I run this code everytime there's a change with the Battlegrounds cards in the game.
$filename = 'https://eu.api.blizzard.com/hearthstone/cards?locale=en_US&
gameMode=battlegrounds&pageSize=1000&access_token='.$token;
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => 
array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$json = file_get_contents($filename,false,$context);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($obj['cards'] as $k => $cur) {
            //Check if the card is new and doesn't exist in the database...
            //INSERT INTO...
}

This worked perfectly fine for many years, however due to the changes it stops after $filename line with the following error:
Warning: file_get_contents(https://eu.api.blizzard.com/hearthstone/cards?
locale=en_US&gameMode=battlegrounds&pageSize=1000&access_token=ACCESS TOKEN): 
Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in ****.php on line 155


You need to add the token to the auth header and give it as a context to file_get_contents, see this question for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers
With a 'Authorization' header which has a value 'Bearer '

Remove the token from the end of $filename, and add 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token to the header array you are already passing to stream_context_create. And remove the \r\n from the already existing entry! Apart from that you should not add carriage return & line feed to your headers yourself to begin with, those aren't even a CR & LF, because you put the value into single quotes.

I've no idea what's this...if you don't know what a HTTP header is, you can get explanations in many places, including here

@C3roe Thank you so much, it's working now!
